# Is there better way to do this filter and sort together in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, sorting, filter

(a) There're lines silimiar as below

```
......, start Mon 10/30 10:08
......, start Thu 12/21 9:21
```

(b) What I want to do: sort the lines by date and time, but want remove lines that start from today

(c) below is the Ruby codes to to implement this function

```
time = Time.new

$mon = time.month
$mday = time.day

# ......

array_tmp = results_all.lines.reject do |x|
    times = x.split(/,/)[1].scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)
    times[0] == $mon &&  times[1] == $mday
end

array_tmp.sort_by {|x| x.split(/,/)[1].scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i)}]
```

My question is:

Is there better and elegant way to do this filter and sort at same time in Ruby?

Comment: @Rajagopalan This code is unreadable in a comment. If this does solve the question, you could add it as an answer instead and explain how this solves the original question.

Comment: sorry, I deleted that answer in the comment. I will add it in the answer section next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we are given:

```
arr = [
  "has , start Mon 10/30 10:08",
  "dog , start Thu 9/24 4:08",4
  "fleas , start Thu 12/21 9:21",
  "Saffi , start Thu 10/29 19:33",
  "My , start Thu 9/7 9:54"
]
```

```
today = Date.today
  #=> #<Date: 2023-12-21 ((2460300j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

One may then write:

```
RGX = /
      \d{1,2}   # match 1 or 2 digits
      \/        # match a forward slash
      \d{1,2}   # match 1 or 2 digits
      [ ]+      # match 1 or more spaces
      \d{1,2}   # match 1 or 2 digits
      :         # match a colon
      \d{2}     # match two digits
      $         # match the end of the string
      /x        # invoke free-spacing regex definition mode
```

```
arr.filter_map do |s|
  dt = string_to_datetime(s)
  [dt, s] unless dt.to_date == today 
end.sort.map(&:last)
  #=> ["My , start Thu 9/7 9:54",
  #    "dog , start Thu 9/24 4:08",
  #    "Saffi , start Thu 10/29 19:33",
  #    "has , start Mon 10/30 10:08"]
```

```
def string_to_datetime(str)
  DateTime.strptime(str[RGX], '%m/%d %H:%M')
end
```

The intermediate calculation

```
arr.filter_map do |s|
  dt = string_to_datetime(s)
  [dt, s] unless dt.to_date == today 
end
  #=> [[#<DateTime: 2023-10-30T10:08:00+00:00 ((2460248j,36480s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     "has , start Mon 10/30 10:08"],
  #    [#<DateTime: 2023-09-24T04:08:00+00:00 ((2460212j,14880s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     "dog , start Thu 9/24 4:08"],
  #    [#<DateTime: 2023-10-29T19:33:00+00:00 ((2460247j,70380s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     "Saffi , start Thu 10/29 19:33"],
  #    [#<DateTime: 2023-09-07T09:54:00+00:00 ((2460195j,35640s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,
  #     "My , start Thu 9/7 9:54"]]
```

displays the array that is being sorted. Each element is a two-element array. The second element is one of the strings being sorted; the first is a `DateTime` instance computed from that string's month-day-time representation. The sorting is primarily done on the first element with the second element used only to break ties when two `DateTime` instances are equal. See the doc [Array#sort](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-sort).

One could alternativly write:

```
arr.reject do |s|
  string_to_datetime(s).to_date == today 
end.sort_by { |s| string_to_datetime(s) }
  #=> ["My , start Thu 9/7 9:54",
  #    "dog , start Thu 9/24 4:08",
  #    "Saffi , start Thu 10/29 19:33",
  #    "has , start Mon 10/30 10:08"]
```

which could expected to be somewhat faster than the first method (because the calculation done by `sort_by`'s block is done just once, even though `string_to_datetime` is called twice). See [Enumerable#sort_by](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-sort_by).

See also [Date::today](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-c-today), [Enumerable#filter_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-filter_map), [DateTime::strptime](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-c-_strptime), [String#[]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and [DateTime#to_date](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.6.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/DateTime.html#method-i-to_date). See [Time#strftime](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-i-strftime) for formatting directives used by `DateTime::strptime`.

Comment: Wow, excellent. This is really the solution I want.  Yes, twice count is not good, just a temporary solution.  filter_map is elegant, I like your solution, thanks a lot.